# How to detect and reject a non-JavaScript post to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Is there a simple way I can detect and reject a non-JavaScript post to an MVC Controller?

Say I have some JavaScript that submits the form via Ajax:

```
function SubmitForm()
{
   var data = $("form").serialize();

   $.post("/MyController/MyAction/", data, function(data, response){
       //Process response
   });

   return false;
}
```

If the user disables JavaScript the form will still post to the controller via a standard form post. I understand that I can't stop it posting but can I detect and reject a non-JavaScript post from the controller and send the user to an error page?

I also understand that this is probably not something that is a standard part of the Controller's functionality so I am wondering if anyone has come up with a trick for achieving this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest)  return RedirectToAction("YourForbiddenAction");`

Comment: omg! thanks so much! I didn't realise it was going to be this simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the form method to "get"? You can then easily detect the method on the server side and only process when the method is post.

```
<form method="get">
...
</form>
```

Edit: Checked the serialize() function docs and it doesn't actually require that your inputs be inside a form. As long as you have a way to select them, such as an enclosing div. So that's an option as well.

Comment: I retract that. I guess I found it odd because I generally don't put inputs intended to be posted inside a form at all but instead pull the inputs out into a javascript object and post as json. Gotta get outta my own little world :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to add a specific hidden input to the form:

```
$('#your_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="got_js" value="1"/>');
```

And then, on the server you can check if there is a `got_js` parameter coming in. If there isn't then you're probably dealing with someone or something that doesn't have JavaScript support. You could do the same thing inside your `SubmitForm` function by adding something else to `data`:

```
var data = $("form").serialize();
data = data ? data + '&got_js=1' : 'got_js=1';
```

Comment: Hey @mu is too short - thanks for the answer - I was originally thinking of going down this road but it seems there are some easier ways to do it - check out @Tahbaza's answer

Comment: Whatever works, I'm just adding more options. I'm guessing that Tahbaza's is just an ASP.net wrapper around Paramount's `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header check, always good to know what's going underneath all the wrappers.

Comment: I think this is the right answer for a different question though, how to detect js enabled on server-side... I'd think your code plus a call to $("your_form").submit() on the doc's onReady would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller check for the headers that jquery sends with ajax requests.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !='XMLHttpRequest'){
   die();
}
```

Edit: just realized that you are not using PHP but asp.net. You should be able to do that same thing though.

---

Added by balexandre

```
if( Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"].ToLower() != "xmlhttprequest" )
    return RedirectToAction("Failed");
```

but in .NET there is a better way:

```
if( !Request.IsAjaxRequest )
    return RedirectToAction("Failed");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, I would prefer an Asp.NET-MVC specific answer though :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I'm actually still learning ASP.NET, so thanks @balexandre for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ActionFilter on your controller action.

[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult AjaxActionMethod()
{
    ....
}

This is not out of the box so you will need to write your own. You can find a good example [here](http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-action-filter-ajax-only-attribute/)